# JavaScript - Moment.js - isBetween() method check if time falls in a range

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to see if **timeNow** falls between a time range **opening** and **closing** :

```
var timeFormat2 = "HH:mm:ss";
var timeNow = "23:12:00"; //(11:12:00 pm)
var opening = "08:00:00"; //(08:00:00 am) morning time
var closing = "00:12:00"; //midnight time (i.e 12:12:00 am)

var isAvailable = moment(timeNow, timeFormat2).isBetween(moment(opening, timeFormat2), moment(closing, timeFormat2));

console.log("will show false >>>> ", isAvailable); //it shows 'false'

var closing1 = "23:45:00";
var isAvailable1 = moment("23:12:00", timeFormat2).isBetween(moment(opening, timeFormat2), moment(closing1, timeFormat2));

console.log("Should show true >>>> ", isAvailable1);
```

Here is a JSfiddle to check it out:

> https://jsfiddle.net/1wuf0rzg/8/

Comment: why should the first console log show false? If the time is now 11:12pm and the opening times are from 8am to 12:12am the next day, shouldn't it be true?

Comment: @derp that should be true and that's what I want, but I can't achieve

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce the concept of "next day". Here I have set the date to be the first day of the month. If the closing time is before the opening time, then I move the closing time to the 2nd day of the month.

```
function isAvailable(opening, closing, now){
    var openingTime = moment(opening, timeFormat2).date(1);
  var closingTime = moment(closing, timeFormat2).date(1);
  var nowTime = moment(now, timeFormat2).date(1);
  if(closingTime.isBefore(openingTime)){
    closingTime.date(2);
  }
  return nowTime.isBetween(openingTime, closingTime);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wuf0rzg/14/

Comment: It does not give accurate values, try to make this `08:00:00` < `00:30:00` < `01:15:00` and it will not work

Comment: if 08:00:00 is the opening time and 00:30:00 is the closing time, then 01:15:00 would not be open? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough data to compute.
`00:12:00` means 12 minutes less than 8 hours before the opening time of the current Date.
Because of that, `23:12:00`will fall out of range.

It would help using different kind of data:

1. opening time.
2. working hours (amount).
3. time now,

in order to be able to determine - if the 'time now' falls inside the time interval with ease.